# Multiple sheets with adjusting lists

Tags: list, loops, if-statement

I've got most of my vba working but I'm having trouble writing a looping code.  I've got a Setup tab with an updating lists, I've already defined the last row.  In the cell to the right I have a drop down Yes/No.  I need it to choose yes.  Go to the Calculation tab that has calculations in cells G5:S5.  I need them copied and pasted values to the last row with data in column A. The Calculation tab has formulas in column B referencing the values in the Setup tab for the list I'm trying to update.  I know how to write the code to get the list the same and pull down the formulas.

Where I'm having a hard time is how can I make this loop when I'm asking it to to refer to multiple last rows and keep track to paste it on the next row until row 7 on one tab and row 2 on the other.  Depending on the list I also need it to insert rows and copy down formulas so the list tab with calculations updates based off the original setup tab.

Right now, I've just recorded me doing the steps but other people use the file and they're vastly exceeding the number of prerecorded lines.  I know how to define all the different pieces I need but I can't bridge the gap on how to get it to loop to "X" when they are different "Xs".  Even though they should be the same length.